# Yii: Add a condition to every query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, frameworks

I want to add a certain condition to every single query that is executed. So a certain column within a table needs to be a certain value. I would use defaultScope, but it applies only to SELECT queries. This certain column of course exist in every table throughout the whole database.

EDIT:

The following table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_user`  int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
```

A certain user having ID 1 shall be able to see, edit etc. records that have the value 1 in `assigned_user`. Using defaultScope he cant see anything else than those, however he is still able to use other query types of the model on records that do not have assigned_user set to 1. This is exactly what I want to restrict, so there is no way he can access other records, by any URL change or different POST variable.

Thanks for every hint, answer and suggestion :)

Comment: Why is it so important for this condition to also apply on other query types?

Comment: Please elaborate your question with examples .

Comment: It shall apply to all query types, so a certain user can only see, edit and delete his own records. defaultScope takes care of seeing records. However using a simple id change in the URL you could point to different records too during editing. And I added an example for my question :)